# Why are some neural network structures unable to fit a problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, xor

I was playing around with an neural network code I wrote for `xor`-ing. I wrote this model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,)))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.2) #for example
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# X_train, Y_train = ([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], [[0], [1], [1], [0]])
X_train = tf.cast([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], tf.float32)
Y_train = tf.cast([0, 1, 1, 0], tf.float32)

# train model and plot loss
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10000)
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.show()

print(model.predict([[0, 1]]))
print(model.predict([[1, 1]]))
print(model.predict([[1, 0]]))
print(model.predict([[0, 0]]))
```

Half of the time I will get 100% accuracy in this model and half of the time I'll get only 75% (sometimes even 50%). Even after 10000 epochs the model can't find a way to fit!

I've noticed that simply switching the layers as shown in the code below would yield 100% accuracy **always**.

```
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,)))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

### The Question

Why is this happening? Why can't this simple model fit well even after 10K epochs while the new model needs less than 500 epochs? What makes specifically the old model converge to that percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you observe that running the same network configuration multiple times leads to very different behavior, it means that the initial weight configuration (which is the only difference between runs) is causing this. However, this does not mean that the initialization scheme is at fault. It can simply mean that gradient descent gets stuck very fast in the parameter space near the initialization that you provided.

One of the prime causes of this happening is a too large learning rate: the network jumps to a local minimum early but gets stuck on the edges of this valley instead of its minimum. If you change your learning rate to `lr=0.01`, you will see that the network has a 100% accuracy every time.

My guess would be that the other network you provide works with a higher learning rate because it has less parameters and therefore a simpler parameter space it needs to operate on.

Comment: Changing it to 0.01 didn't work but changing it to 0.004 did! Thank you :)   So can a neural network always be "tweaked" to make it work well? Or are there times when a certain combination of hidden layers makes it impossible to work?

Comment: If the solution space is very restrictive (such as in XOR), it can happen that the problem can be unsolvable for some classes (e.g. it's impossible to solve XOR without nonlinearities and at least 1 hidden layer). In more realistic problems and larger networks, you can observe similar effects but they're usually a result of more complex interactions between multiple hyperparameters. Basically, ever network has to be tweaked to work well on a given dataset but there is no hard guarantee that we can always achieve large accuracies without overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

For xor problem architecture 2 hidden 1 output neuron is able to solve it. First thing which I want to mention is our perception of problem. I understand that this one seems to us humans as trivial, but that doesn't mean that is also trivial for these easy networks.

XOR is typical exaple of lineary non-separable problem. From my experience, when I try to solve it with [2, 1] architecture I was successfull but it also takes many epochs.

Second thing, these architectures are sometimes not able solve at given epochs. Is almost guaranteed that if you train longer, you reach the conclusion(sometimes way too long).

Third thing is. I mentioned [2, 1] is ale to solve it. Lets focus at 2. 2 hidden neurons means that you have two non-linear combinations of input. So you map 2-Dimensional to 2-Dimensional space, nonlinearity gave you chance that at this new space will be inputs separable. And here is the thing, maybe is hard for neural network this separation at this mapping. When you use 16 hidden you create 16 nonlinear combinations and from your results we see that is easier to find the good separations.

Comment: very interesting! Thank you for the great answer. Is there some kind of way to decide what layer models are the best for each problem?

Comment: The best approach to this is try to find someone who solve same or similar problem and try to use his architecture(number of layers, count of neurons inside the layers). If not feasible, try-error. There are some general recommendations, when you work with images is likely you will end with convolution layers. NLP reccurent/attention.